# Inheritance and protected attribute

Tags: c++, xcode4

I'm writing the following structure :

```
class F {
protected:
    F* i;
public:
    F(){i=NULL;}
    virtual F* clone()const=0;
    virtual double operator()(double x)const=0; 
    virtual F* derivative()const=0;
    virtual double inverse(double y)const=0; 
    virtual ~F(){}

};

class T : public F{
    string n;
public:
    T(string n_);
    F* clone()const;
    double operator()(double x)const;
    F* derivative()const;
    double inverse(double y)const;
    ~T(){}
};
```

I'm writing method 'T::derivative' right now. My two first lines are :

```
F* T::derivative()const
{
    F* deriv;
    deriv->i=clone();

}

F* T::clone()const
{
    return new T(n);
}
```

but Xcode tells me for the second line in 'T::derivative' that `'i' is a protected member of 'F`. 
I can't understand why I can't have access to it when I'm in 'T', which inherits from 'F'.

Answer (score 2):

A member of class `T` can only access protected members of objects of class `T` (including the currect object), not arbitrary objects of class `F` or other subtypes.

Whatever `deriv` is supposed to be (at the moment, it's an uninitialised pointer, so you'd have big problems even if the code did compile), it will have to be `T*` (or a subtype of `T`) in order to access `i` through it. Either that, or `i` will need to be more widely accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Since  protected members are only accesible to (Sub Class ) T (here) (since only derievedd class from base F). To access i (protected member) instantiate T and use i .
Here change this to

```
F* deriv;
T* deriv;
```

and you have your error disappeared.

Comment: It's nothing to do with being abstract. You could access public members of the abstract type in this context; just not private members, or protected members via pointers to types other than `T`, due to the access rules for all classes (abstract or otherwise).